# How is a different CPP file being able to use the function from another just by defining it? C++

Tags: c++, header

Here is a very simple explanation, I have 2 cpp files:

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

DWORD WINAPI Entry();

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, 
DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
switch (fdwReason)
{
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&Entry, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

Mapping.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
DWORD WINAPI Entry()
{

}
```

Now from what I understand, I would need to define a Header file and include the definition of the method and then include that file inside dllmain.cpp. However this example works just fine.

So, how does dllmain.cpp just by defining DWORD WINAPI Entry(); know the method implementation inside Mapping.cpp?

Comment: 1) `DWORD WINAPI Entry();` is a declaration, not a definition. Definition is in Mapping.cpp. And the linker is responsible for linking the function calls to definitions. 2) "_from what I understand, I would need to define a Header file and include the definition of the method and then include that file inside dllmain.cpp._" Do you know how `#include` directive works? It is just glorified copy-paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that matters is that you have a declaration for the function `Entry()`, and you accomplish that with the line:

```
DWORD WINAPI Entry();
```

in the file.

Header files are just a convenient way to avoid having to write the same thing in every program that uses `Entry()`. When you `#include` a header file, it simply acts as if the contents of that file were inserted in this source file.

The header file doesn't tell the compiler where the function is actually defined. That's done by linking with `Mapping.o`, which is created when you compile `Mapping.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

A function "definition" without a function body like `DWORD WINAPI Entry();` is called a function prototype; It basically defines the return type and the function parameter list, and this is all a compiler needs to generate code for calling such a function and dealing with the return value. It does not matter if the function prototype is declared in a header file or in a CPP file. The only thing is that the compiler "knows" the prototype before reaching code where the function is called.

Header files are just a common "convention" to expose the functions provided by a translation unit to other translation units. But technically a header file is just  piece of code that is meant to be "included" (i.e. textually inserted) at the place where preprocessor directive `#include "someheader.h"` is given in some code.